# Radio Button with React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, storybook

My Radio Button is not working properly, the biggest problem is that the checked attribute is not getting set when i click on radio item.

Any idea why it is not working properly and how to achieve above points?

Please see the Snippet Below, it is not working here don't know why.

```js
class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        Group 1: <RadioButton />
        Group 2: <RadioButtonGroup />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

import React, { useState } from "react"

interface SharedProps {
  /**
   * Specify whether the control is disabled
   */
  disabled?: boolean

  /**
   * Specify whether the <RadioButton> is currently checked
   */
  defaultChecked?: boolean

  /**
   * Provide where label text should be placed
   */
  labelPosition: "right" | "left"

  /**
   * Provide a name for the underlying `<input>` node
   */
  name: string

  /**
   * Provide an optional `onChange` hook that is called each time the value of
   * the underlying `input` changes
   */
  onChange?: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}

export interface RadioButtonProps extends SharedProps {
  /**
   * Provide label text to be read by screen readers when interacting with the
   * control
   */
  labelText: string

  /**
   * Specify the value of the <RadioButton>
   */
  value: string | number

  /**
   * Specify whether the <RadioButton> is currently checked
   */
  checked: boolean

  /**
   * Specify whether the label should be hidden, or not
   */
  hideLabel: boolean

  /**
   * Event – on click
   */
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void

  // Radio Btn Label next to Radio input.
  inputLabel?: string

  // Field required
  required?: boolean
}

export interface RadioButtonGroupProps extends SharedProps {
  // Radio Btn Label next to Radio input.
  inputLabelGroup?: string

  /**
   * Provide a collection of components to render in the group
   */
  items: Array<RadioButtonProps>
  /**
   * Provide where radio buttons should be placed
   */
  orientation: "horizontal" | "vertical"

  /**
   * Specify the value of the <RadioButton>
   */
  valueSelected: string | number
}

export const RadioButton = ({
  labelText,
  value,
  checked,
  hideLabel,
  onClick,
  inputLabel,
  required,
  disabled,
  defaultChecked,
  labelPosition,
  name,
  onChange,
}: RadioButtonProps) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(checked)
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id="radiobutton-1"
        type="radio"
        name={name}
        required={required}
        disabled={disabled}
        aria-label="example"
        value={value}
        checked={isChecked}
        onChange={onChange}
        onClick={() => setIsChecked(!isChecked)}
        defaultChecked={defaultChecked}
      />

      <label htmlFor="radiobutton-1">
        {!hideLabel && <span aria-label={labelText}>{inputLabel}</span>}
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}

// Default Value of hideLabel
RadioButton.defaultProps = {
  hideLabel: false,
  checked: false,
}

export const RadioButtonGroup = ({
  orientation,
  valueSelected,
  disabled,
  // defaultChecked,
  labelPosition,
  inputLabelGroup,
  name,
  items,
  onChange,
}: RadioButtonGroupProps) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(Number)
  const mappedItems = items.map(
    ({ inputLabel, labelText, value, hideLabel, required }, index) => (
      <RadioButton
        name={name}
        key={index}
        inputLabel={inputLabel}
        required={required}
        
        checked={active === index}
        
        onClick={() => setActive(index)}
        onChange={onChange}
        labelText={labelText}
        value={value}
        disabled={disabled}
        hideLabel={hideLabel}
        
        labelPosition={labelPosition}
      />
    )
  )
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{inputLabelGroup}</label>
      {mappedItems}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is with the `name` attribute on your input. You give each input a different name so you make each input belong to a different group. All radio inputs must have the same name (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp)) or no `name` attribute at all.

BTW, in most cases you don't need to put an `id` attribute when writing React code.

Also the `useState` function accepts the default state as parameter and not the type.

See this simple code snippet:

```js
class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        Group 1: <RadioGroup />
        Group 2: <RadioGroup />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const RadioGroup = () =>{
   const [active, setActive] = React.useState(0);
   return (
    <div>
      <input type="radio" checked={active==0} onClick={() => setActive(0)} />
      <input type="radio" checked={active==1} onClick={() => setActive(1)} />
    </div>
   );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Root />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

And if I can give you a small tip: When trying to figure out a problem in you code, try to simplify the code as much as possible and remove unnecessary elements like styled elements and such. And if you post this code to SO it will be easer to review your code.

Comment: thanks but can you please check my inputted snippet once again..
i have made some changes. To make it more easier to understand.#